# How to check if a character is an apostrophe?

Tags: java, char

I need to check if a character is an apostrophe. This is my code so far:

```
public boolean isWordCharacter(int c) {
if ((char) c == '\'')
    return true;
else return Character.isLetter(c);
}
```

However, it never actually gets into the `if ((char) c == '\'')` part. Is there something wrong with the way I check it? Thanks!

Comment: That code looks just fine to me; your problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: There's no need to cast `c` to a `char`.

Comment: Not an answer per se, but flat character parsing is indicative of a few potential anti-patterns. Have you considered [Java's regular expression facilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) for your needs?

Comment: @MrGomez, I'm not fully convinced of that, just because regexes have considerable overhead.  If you just care about one character at a time, regexes may well be overkill.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Neither am I. I just find it polite to put it out there, if and only if it serves the needs of the OP (and people Googling here) better. :)

Comment: Just tried your code. It's works fine. Maybe the c parameter is wrong. Can you show us the call to isWordCharacter().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply use `if(c=='\'')` without cast. Or you can use ascii value of apostrophe which is 39. `if (c==39)` will do.

> it never actually gets into the 'if ((char) c == '\'') part

The only reason for this could you never pass apostrophe to isWordCharacter(). You can verify it by manually sending `39` or `'\''` to that function.